# MySQL: show content in permalinks by row ID

Tags: php, mysql, permalinks

I am trying to make my own CMS and I am pretty new in php and mysql. Let me get to the point:

So far I've created news in index page with "read more" permalinks (which means, when I press read more, it moves me to other page e.g. `/readmore.php?id=[news ID]` and in that page the only content is those specific news i.e specific row from table. What I'm stuck with is getting that specific row ID in that permalink.

Let me show the code that currently works for me.

index file with news:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
   {
/*... title, news content... */
   echo "<a href='readmore.php?id=".$row['ID']."'>".$read_more_link."</a></div>";
}
```

readmore.php with exact row (for example readmore.php?id=1201) :

```
$params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$str = $params;
$id1 = $str[strlen($str)-1];
$id2 = $str[strlen($str)-2];
$id3 = $str[strlen($str)-3];
$id4 = $str[strlen($str)-4];
$news_id = "$id4$id3$id2$id1";

$query = "SELECT * FROM naujiena WHERE ID='$news_id'";
```

Basically what it does, it recovers 4 last digits from address bar and searches for those news with that 4 digit ID

It's a very primitive way of doing this, but I'm stuck with this for a few days and can't find a way out.

What I've tried before, is to create a variable with session in the `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` loop, it shows IDs in the index page as it should, but in readmore page only the last one or the first one (depends on desc or asc) which was quite obvious to expect

Can you help me? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the values in the query string by name in the `$_GET` array.

For example, `$_GET['id']` will be the value of the `id=<ID>` part of the query string. It works for every field of the query string.

```
// url : readmore.php?id=1201
$news_id = intval($_GET['id']);
// now, $news_id contains the value 1201
$query = "SELECT * FROM naujiena WHERE ID='$news_id'";
```

You can read the official help : [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or one of the various tutorial you can find on the web : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

**Update**

Since you accepted my answer, I feel obligated to also throw a word about SQL injection. You should always sanitize any input you're using in a SQL query with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). You can find more details on Wikipedia : [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or in the PHP documentation : [SQL Injection](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Since your IDs are numeric values, you can also ensure that. I updated the code snippet to do this with [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

Comment: Thank you for your concern, I have already placed `mysql_rea_escape_string()` on my login and comment forms. And thank you for `intval` thing! Appreciate that.

Comment: you should escape **everything**, there's so many way to inject something in the database, you would'nt want to take any chances !

Answer (score 2):

To extract the parameters of query-string in php, use `$_GET` super-global, like this:

```
$_GET["id"]
```

Also note, that the any data provided by a remote (user, browser, etc) may be forged.
So, an attacker may as well send you `?id=0; DROP TABLE users` or something alike.

Read more about [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

It is always a good idea to validate the input.
You're expecting the *id* to be an integer, so in order to be safe, you can check `if(ctype_digit($_GET["id"]))) ...`

And finally, it is also a good idea to sanitize any input you are using in SQL statements. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), or consider using [`PDO`](http://il.php.net/PDO)

Comment: So what are you saying I should make line like this: `$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"])` ? (or / and also) make check with `if(ctype_digit(...)))..` ?

Comment: yes, always validate data, and always escape it. if you do both, you're on a safe side

Answer (score 1):

To get a specific HTTP-GET variable you can use [`$_GET["variableName"]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). In your case you could get the ID like this:

`$news_id = $_GET["id"];`